# How to fold all :noexport: sections on initial loading of any org file?

Tags: org-mode

In writing documents using org mode, I organize contents that are not supposed to show up in the final product into sections with an `:noexport:` attribute. These are mostly notes and auxiliary code blocks. So, I often fold each of them manually so that I can see the main text.

*Is there a way to configure Emacs to automatically fold/hide these `noexport` sections when any `.org` file is initially loaded?*

(This is with Emacs 27 under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, org-mode 9.4.6).

Comment: Initial visibility is normally [controlled via the VISIBILITY property](https://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html). Maybe setting that manually is OK in your case.

Comment: I would recommend @Juancho's solution, although there are (more complicated but less manual) alternatives. E.g. you can add a function to the `find-file-hook` that checks for Org mode files first and then uses `org-map-entries` to find entries with a `noexport` tag and fold them with `org-cycle`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the (more complicated but less manual) solution I mentioned in my comment.

Here's an Org mode file with some headlines marked `noexport` and others not. It also includes a `noexport` code section with two code blocks: the first one defines a function and adds it to the `find-file-hook` and the second cleans up the hook if you decide you don't like it. To see it in action, open the file in Emacs, evaluate the first code block with `C-c C-c`, and then close the file and reopen it: the `noexport` sections (and only those) should be folded:

```el
#+STARTUP: showall

* foo
foo

* bar                                                         :noexport:
bar

* baz
baz

* Code                                                        :noexport:

#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (defun ndk/org-fold-noexport-sections ()
    (org-map-entries #'org-cycle "noexport" 'file))

  (add-hook 'find-file-hook #'ndk/org-fold-noexport-sections)
#+end_src


#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (remove-hook 'find-file-hook #'ndk/org-fold-noexport-sections)
#+end_src
```

The `#+STARTUP: showall` keyword makes sure that Org mode will start in a known folding state: with everything unfolded. When the hook is run and the function is evaluated, it is going to walk the file, visiting every headline that matches the `noexport` tag and it will run `org-cycle` on it: since it is open to begin with, that will fold it. Another way to do that is through the variable `org-startup-folded`: the default value `showeverything` is equivalent to the `#+STARTUP:` setting above, but it applies to every Org mode file, so you don't have to worry about setting it per-file.

You can clean up by running the second code block with `C-C C-c`: that will delete the function from the `find-file-hook`. OTOH, if you are happy with it, copy the first code block into your Emacs init file.

@Juancho's solution (see his comment above) is simpler (but more manual); it's also using built-in Org mode facilities only, so there is no extra baggage (like the code block above) needed.